# Deep level menu using bootstrap 3 for wordpress issue

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation, wordpress-theming

I am working on a wordpress template using Bootstrap 3 and am now creating a custom Wordpress menu. I am using the bootstrap navwalker (https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker).

I followed this Tutsplus tutorial exactly ...
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-bootstrap-navbar-into-wordpress-theme--wp-33410

The issue is I have 3 sub menu levels, but the bootstrap 3 is just supporting 2 sub menu levels.

**I tried a lot of solution on the web and her in this site but nothing fixed my problem.**

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution from this bootply.com link: http://www.bootply.com/92442. 
And the third sub menu level worked fine But I have another issues regarding JS. When I click on the sub menu Item it collapse. but when I want to un-collapse it doesn't work, a screen shot to explain:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVPvX.png